# Troubleshooting Paypal

Tags: paypal, jqtouch

I have a paypal button within a jqtouch site as follows

```
  <div id="paypal">
  <div class="toolbar">
  <h5>Pay online</h5>
  <a href="#" class="back">Back</a>
  </div>
        <div class="s-scrollwrapper"  >
              <div>
              <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr"method="post">
              <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
              <input type="hidden" name="business" value="----@-----------">
              <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Test Item">
              <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.00">
              <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="NZD">
              <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
              <input type="hidden" name="bn"value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
              <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
              <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1"height="1">
              </form>
              </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Taping the paypal button does nothing. Firebuging sees a `post` request with a result code of `302` followed by a `get` that is cancelled. If I put the button on a page outside of jqtouch it seems to work not problem. How would you trouble shoot this?

Chrome console shows the following. In the non-jqtouch the initiator is `(other)`

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jqtouch submits all forms as with AJAX by default. This upsets the paypal button. Add the following to you initialization

```
 formSelector: false
```

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a valid PayPal button.  The 302 is redirecting you to login since you aren't posting a valid set of data.  I would recommend setting up a [Sandbox Account](https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/home) and cut and paste the actual button snippet.
It should look more like this [PayPal button sample](https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_xclick_techview_outside).

```
<form name="_xclick" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="me@mybusiness.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Teddy Bear">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="12.99">
    <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynow_LG.gif" 
    border="0" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```